# Max-height (and aspect ratio) issue in Chrome, when I want to make an image gallery with floating height

Tags: css, google-chrome, aspect-ratio, floating

A few weeks ago I working on [this](http://lantosistvan.com/temp/lantosistvan.com-portfolio-hor/) site. This is my next portfolio site. I want to make this structure, when I finish:

- Header
- Horizontal image gallery with floating height
- Footer

I want to create something similar, just like the [22slides.com](http://www.basilvargas.com/lifestyle) portfolio sites for photographers. If you change your browser's window size or press full screen button, the img element or the image's div automatically change his height.

I putted in the CSS a "max-height" parameter, to prevent the images never become bigger than their original resolution. It's a serious issue on huge resolution screens. but in Chrome it's not working properly, because the aspect ratios become wrong. If you press full screen, the aspect ratio more bad. In every other latest browser (Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE8-9) working normally. I created a custome CSS only for chrome with this command (but now I uncommented this in HTML to show you the Chrome aspect ratio problem):

```
#portfolio img { max-height: none; }
```

So with this line, the images using the biggest possible height in Chrome and the aspect ratios are correct. But it's a problem for me. I not want that a 1024x683px image showed bigger than his actual resolution on a FullHD monitor.

I think the best solution, if there's a javascript, which is dynamically escribe a width and height for every single image and keep the original aspect ratio. 22slides.com using something similar javascript, but I'm not a javascript programmer at all. :(

The images HTML structure:

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS (max-height is very little number, just to show you the problem in Chrome):

```
#portfolio { white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
#portfolio img { height: 100%; width: auto !important; min-height: 150px; max-height: 350px; }
```

I'm using this Jquery Javascript to dynamically change the image's height and bring back the image's overflow on the screen with 130px negative height. Probably not this script causing the problem, becuase if I turn it off, the aspect ratios are more bad in Chrome:

```
// Dynamical vertical resizing on images and Correct the height (to not overflow the screen)
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){ // On load
    $('#portfolio img').css({'height':(($(window).height())-130)+'px'}); // Adjust the number if you change something in CSS
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
    $('#portfolio img').css({'height':(($(window).height())-130)+'px'}); // Adjust the number if you change something in CSS
    });
});
```

I need help! Thank You!

**Update:**

This javascript written by "Emphram Stavanger" and "nick_w" seems to solve my image fit to browser height problem:
[Imagefit vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314160/imagefit-vertically)

I tried and it's perfectly working with one single image. The image fitting in the available viewport window perfectly, with correct aspect ratio! There is a visual explanation for our problem made by "Emphram Stavanger":
http://www.swfme.com/view/1064342

JsFiddle demo (Basicly it's Emphram Stavanger's code, I just putted in the changes by nick_W, changed Jquery to latest and I putted after the show link:

http://jsfiddle.net/YVqAW/show/

I not tried yet with horizontal scrolling image website, but it's already a big step!

UPDATE 2:

SOLUTION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303672/horizontal-image-slideshow-javascript-not-working-properly-with-portrait-oriente

(And I need help again...) :)

Comment: It's been a while since you asked this question. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Yes I found it, but I need help in another aspect: :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303672/horizontal-image-slideshow-javascript-not-working-properly-with-portrait-oriente

Answer (score 1):

A little late but you can use a div with background-image and set background-size: contain instead of an img tag:

```
div.image{
    background-image: url("your/url/here");
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Now you can just set your div size to whatever you want and not only will the image keep its aspect ratio it will also be centralized both vertically and horizontally.

The background-size property is ie>=9 only though.