# Imagefit vertically

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm using Oliver Boermans' jQuery plugin for fitting images into a container with 100% width and height (so, essentially, the viewport); http://www.ollicle.com/eg/jquery/imagefit/

The meat of the plugin is this;

```
$(img)
    .width('100%').each(function()
    {
        $(this).height(Math.round(
            $(this).attr('startheight')*(dim.outerWidth/$(this).attr('startwidth')))
        );
    })
    .css({marginTop: Math.round( ($(window).height() - $(img).height()) / 2 )});
```

The `startwidth` and `startheight` attributes contain the image's actual pixel dimensions.

Now, this works absolutely perfectly when the image is wider than the viewport. However, I found that when the viewport is vertically shorter than the image, it doesn't fit the image into the viewport vertically.

How can I modify this plugin to take vertical fitting into account in addition to horizontal, so that whatever the dimensions and aspect ratio of the viewport may be, every inch of the image is always displayed fully?

I prepared a fiddle to play with; http://jsfiddle.net/NXJCd/ - adjust the Result division's size to see the plugin in action. If you set the height as shorter than the fitted image, the top and bottom edges of the image get cut.

**EDIT:** So after some confusion, I want to clarify; I want to proportionally *fit* the image inside the container. All of the image needs to always be visible, but never larger than its original dimensions. I've visualized it below. The jQuery plugin I have for this works for horizontal fitting (Examples A and C), but it doesn't fit vertically (Example B). That's what I want to solve.

[image: Examples]

**EDIT2:** After some further confusion, I even made an animation detailing how I want it to behave; http://www.swfme.com/view/1064342

Comment: It occurred to me that you are most likely doing something like this: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Actually, no. I want to always display every single pixel of the image. It's not so much a background as it is a content image that should be displayed at its maximum resolution, and if the viewport is too small to display it entirely, proportionally size it down to the largest size that fits.

Comment: Oh, so you just want the image to _fit_ the viewport proportionally...

Comment: Yes, but never larger than its original proportions. For this, Oliver's plugin is perfect, except for the fact that it doesn't adjust the height of the image when the viewport is wider than tall. See the updated question with visualization :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `one` function worked for me:

```
one : function(img){
    var parentDim = $(img).parent().getHiddenDimensions();        
    var heightWidthRatio = $(img).attr('startheight') / $(img).attr('startwidth');
    var newWidth, newHeight;

    //Width > height.
    if(heightWidthRatio < 1) {            
        newWidth = parentDim.outerWidth > $(img).attr('startwidth')
            ? $(img).attr('startwidth') : parentDim.outerWidth;
        newHeight = Math.round(newWidth * heightWidthRatio);

        if(newHeight > parentDim.outerHeight) {
            newHeight = parentDim.outerHeight;
            newWidth = Math.round(newHeight / heightWidthRatio);
        }
    }
    //Height >= width.
    else {            
        newHeight = parentDim.outerHeight > $(img).attr('startheight')
            ? $(img).attr('startheight') : parentDim.outerHeight;
        newWidth = Math.round(newHeight / heightWidthRatio);

        if(newWidth > parentDim.outerWidth) {
            newWidth = parentDim.outerWidth;
            newHeight = Math.round(newWidth * heightWidthRatio);
        }
    }

    $(img).width(newWidth).height(newHeight)
        .css({marginTop: Math.round(($(window).height() - $(img).height()) / 2 )});
}
```

Note that this instead uses the size of the parent `div` - because image size is set to 100% in the CSS, it meant that the initial image dimensions were larger than the containing div, which can cause issues the first time the function is called.

**Edit:**

I have updated the code above, but the changes are:

```
newWidth = parentDim.outerWidth;
```

Becomes:

```
newWidth = parentDim.outerWidth > $(img).attr('startwidth') ? $(img).attr('startwidth') : parentDim.outerWidth;
```

And

```
newHeight = parentDim.outerHeight;
```

Becomes:

```
newHeight = parentDim.outerHeight > $(img).attr('startheight') ? $(img).attr('startheight') : parentDim.outerHeight;
```

These changes should ensure that images do not expand to larger than their actual dimensions.

Comment: This is definitely closest! However, I noticed that if the parent `div` is larger than the image's original dimensions, the image's height is stretched unproportionally. If the image is smaller than the surrounding `div`, it should simply be centered (as demonstrated in the Flash animation); how would that be implemented in your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but I've put together a [variant](http://jsfiddle.net/gguuL/) which always display a full screen image, but still has the aspect ratio, otherwise the image might look quite distorted:

```
function optSizeImage( selector ) {
    var obj;
    if(typeof selector === 'undefined' || !selector) {
        selector = '.visual img, .gallery-box img';
    }
    obj = ( typeof ( selector ) == 'string' ) ? $( selector ) : selector;
    function resizeImg() {
        var imgwidth = obj.width(),
          imgheight = obj.height(),
          winwidth = $(window).width(),
          winheight = $(window).height(),
          widthratio = winwidth / imgwidth,
          heightratio = winheight / imgheight,
          widthdiff = heightratio * imgwidth,
          heightdiff = widthratio * imgheight;
       if(heightdiff>winheight) {
        obj.css({
          width: winwidth+'px',
          height: heightdiff+'px'
        });
       } else {
        obj.css({
          width: widthdiff+'px',
          height: winheight+'px'
        });     
       }
    }
   resizeImg();
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  optSizeImage($("img"));
  $(window).bind('resize',function(){
    optSizeImage($("img"));
  });
});
```

Comment: This I guess is the closest, but what I'm looking for would always make sure all of the image is displayed, 'letterboxing' it if the aspect ratio of the viewport doesn't match that of the image, and never bigger than its original dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Does aspect ratio matter? Check out this CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Sdush/

Click the "Enlarge outer div" link to see the image expand to fill.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="out">
  <img id="expand" src="someImage.jpg" />
</div>
```

... and the CSS:

```
#out{width:800px;height:600px;}
#expand{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

But again, this doesn't respect aspect ratios of the image, and needs a discernible width for the container.

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to much differ from setting the height and width directly into the image itself. What I need is proportionally resizing the image to *fit*, not cover, its container. I'm not aware of any pure-CSS solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't max-width and max-height give you what you want?  set max width and max height to the container size, and it should be limited to the container size but aspect ratio will be kept by the browser.

Html:

```
<img id="testimg" src="https://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
```

JS code:

```
i = -25;
function resizeme() {
    var theimg = $("#testimg");
    i++;
    $(theimg).css("max-width", 275 + (i * 5));
    $(theimg).css("max-height", 95 + (i * 2));
}
setInterval(function () {resizeme();}, 500);
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNpkH/4/).